# How tou get values from an array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm connecting to a 3rd party API can dd the complete result. As a test I'm getting all countries with a name and a type. Now I would like to show just 1 countryname as a test. I'm not sure how to do this.

I tried $countries[0]->name and $countries[0]['name'] but both don't seem to work

Current result:

```
array:69 [▼
  0 => NamedCriterion {#218 ▼
    -name: "Andorra"
    -type: "Country"
    -value: "13"
  }
  1 => NamedCriterion {#235 ▶}
  2 => NamedCriterion {#233 ▶}
  3 => NamedCriterion {#220 ▶}
  4 => NamedCriterion {#230 ▶}
  5 => NamedCriterion {#223 ▶}
  6 => NamedCriterion {#221 ▶}
  7 => NamedCriterion {#219 ▶}
```

From this call:

```
$response = $search->getCriteria([], ['Country'], []);

if (!$response->isError()) {
  $criterionSets = $response->getCriterionSets();
  $countryCriterionSet = $criterionSets[0];
  $countries = $countryCriterionSet->getCriteria();
  $resultCount = $response->getResultCount();
}
dd($countries);
    }
```

So I would for example just get Andorra as a result of my call and dd that.

Comment: `$countries[0]->getName()` probably

Comment: That's it thanks! @Farkie